# Convolutional Neural Network for 3D point cloud?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, conv-neural-network

Can Convolutional Neural Networks or Deep Architectures be used for generating 3D point clouds ?

Comment: What do you mean? We use NNs to *classify* 3D points, eg. We don't use NNs to *generate* data. There are plenty of RNGs for that.

Comment: I guess taking a look at this article might answer your question regarding the CNN of deep learning for point clouds. [3D CNN for landing zone detection](https://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/2015/3/maturana-root.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can treat it as a **regression** problem and generate 3D point coordinates (3 real values) as an output of your neural network.

Comment: Why would a point in 3D be composed of 6 values?

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake, 3.